# Is G a base for a Topology in X

Tags: general-topology

This problem is from Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $A=\{a,b\}$, $B=\{b,c\}$ and $G=\{\emptyset,X,A,B\}$. Is $G$ a base for a topology in X?

I am looking to see if my proof is correct. Assume $G$ is a base for $\tau$ a topology on X. If $\tau$ is a topology with base $G$ then we need to be able to construct all open sets of $\tau$ from elements of $G$. The open sets constructible from unions of elements of $G$ are clearly the elements of $G$ themselves so $\tau=\{\emptyset,X,A,B\}$ is our topology. But this is a contradiction as finite intersections of open sets must be open, however $A\cap B = \{\ b\}$ which is not open in $\tau$.

Comment: There is a characterization of a set of subsets being a base of a topology that is in your textbook and that you should use.

Comment: I know that I can prove it like that but I was wondering if my proof is correct

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $A \cap B=\{b\}$ is not a union of members of $G$. So $G$ is not a base for some topology. So essentially your idea works.

Many text books have the following necessary condition for $\mathcal{B}$ to be a base for some topology, which is a reformulation of that idea in a moee formal form:

$$\forall B,B' \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B\cap B': \exists B'' \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B'' \subseteq B\cap B'$$

and this is violated here for $B=A$, $B'=B$ and $x=b$.